# how to get the character ideographic comma

Tags: ideographic-comma

Kindly suggest how to get the `ideographic comma` (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+3001) in `XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX`

Comment: With xeCJK I just paste that character in and it builds fine. Can you be more precise about your question?

Comment: @WillieWong Can you provide the `MWE`? please

Comment: Sorry, but it is rather up to the OP to provide a MWE first. If you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you just need to load a font that contains this codepoint (for example Noto Sans CJK). If you just input the character just like this `、` it should show up in the PDF. If you only need it a few times and don't use a CJK input method, you can also type `\char"3001 `. But it is rather difficult to help you, without knowing anything about your set up.

Comment: An MWE for XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX would really just be `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}\begin{document}、\end{document}` or `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}\begin{document}\char"3001\end{document}`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht and `WillieWong` it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. it's just a character. My browser used the Windows font SimSun so I used the same here

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{SimSun}
\begin{document}

[、]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works